# UI enhancement: allow any user to see the raw source of posts

Tags: feature-request, markdown, view-source

I hope this is not a duplicate, I couldn't find anything related (sorry if I'm wrong, flag it and I'll remove it in this case).

Sometimes I find posts whose formatting is interesting and which I'd like to learn from. In these cases I reach for the "edit" link to browse the raw source. I find this a bit dangerous. I always worry to change something by mistake, and now that I reached the 2k rep where no peer review acts as a filter I'm more worried.

Wouldn't be useful to have also a link that allows to see the raw post source without entering edit mode? This could also be a nice learning instrument for newbies, since they could learn how to use markdown by seeing what other posters did.

Comment: You can install this script to always see link to revisions: http://stackapps.com/q/2047/22190

Comment: I was just about to ask the same. **Questions that may already have your answer** pointed me here. My issue, however, is not the danger of editing by mistake (ok, I just need to be careful), but the **Edit** option being *disabled*. Also, I don't know how to look at the comments' source codes, they are not editable (except your own, only for a few minutes though). Your question definitely deserves a +1 (it was -2, now it's -1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's already available in the posts's edit history: there's a "source" link on all revisions that affect the post's body.

> [image]

If the post hasn't been edited, you can type in the URL manually:

```
http://<your.site>/posts/<post id>/revisions
```

The post id is in the URL for questions, and it's the first number in the URL you get by clicking the "share" button on answers.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I never noticed that! This is useful and solves *my* problem, but I think that for newbies it could be much easier a `source` link near `share|edit|flag`. Moreover in the case the post hasn't been edited yet, typing the URL explicitly is a PITA compared to clicking `edit` for a quick glance.

Comment: I don't think it's worth it. Just click edit.

Comment: Mmm, but low rep newbies (those that would gain more from the feature) won't be able to do it. BTW I cannot find the min rep level to edit a post (OMG!), so maybe I'm barking at the wrong tree. What's the min level?

Comment: this doesn't work with comments and locked posts, however.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati: you can edit posts even if you're not logged in. No rep required.

Comment: @JanDvorak: the URL "trick" works on locked posts (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/9134/revisions). There's nothing for comments though indeed.

Comment: Thanks! So this solves a relevant part of the problem. It remains a usability problem. Moreover I fear that most newbies wouldn't touch the `edit` link just to "look under the hood" (I might be proven wrong though). I still find it a useful feature, I don't know if it would be too "heavy" to implement.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati: your target audience isn't just any noob. It's someone who cares enough to format their posts properly that they're actually searching for similar stuff. Or are very curious. I wouldn't think they'd be scared of clicking "edit" to see what happens. (Or, even, read the docs!)

Comment: Mmm, yes, you are probably right.

Comment: So... is there a way to see a comment's source code? @JanDvorak mentioned it, but no one responded.

Comment: @Heimdall: not in the UI. Maybe with either the API or Data Explorer if you care enough.

Comment: @JanDvorak I've worked it out (partially): if you want to see *MathJax* code in the comment, look at it using the Stack Exchange app (works on Android). For some reason the app doesn't render MathJax in *comments*, just in questions and answers.